# Visual Basic 19 - WebView2 - Auto click a webpage button

Tags: vb.net, automation, visual-studio-2019, webbrowser-control, webview2

I have this old VB web browser that I made to auto log me into my social accounts.
It would do this by automatically entering my credentials, and clicking "Log In".
I enjoyed the privacy of "my own" browser, and I didn't need to remember my passwords.
However, recently my hard drive failed, and I failed to make a backup...

I would love to re-create this with the *WebView2* (Chromium-Edge) package as the default *WebBrowser* control is having issues now.
(I understand there are better options for security and storage of passwords, this is just a nostalgic project.)
However, I'm having trouble converting the code.

Here's what I can remember basing my code from:

```
Dim WebElements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
For each PageElement As HtmlElement In WebElements
    If PageElement.GetAttribute("value") = "Log In" Then
        PageElement.InvokeMember("click")
    End if
Next
```

It would be a plus if someone could help me figure out how to auto-fill text fields in *WebView2* too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(String)` method to call javascript. `ExecuteScriptAsync`is async and must be prepended with `await`.

Something like this:

```
await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('[value=\"Log In\"]').click();");
```

where `vebWiew21` is the name of `WebView2` control.

That should log you in.

To set the value of textboxes, you need to know the `id` attribute of the input fields, you want to change, then you use `ExecuteScriptAsync` to change the value, like this:

```
await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('the id').value = 'your name'";);
```

and similar with password. Of course these values should be set before you call `click()`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, I'm not sure I'm using the first line of code properly. I imported it, and if I'm not getting Asynchronous errors, the application will run but the "Log In" button is not pressed and the application freezes for a few seconds. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you press 'F12' to bring up the Developer tool. Check that the elements actually have the values you expect.